# Publish Multiple topics by a Producer in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka. I created both Producer which will post messages into one topic and Consumers getting those messages from that topic.My question is how can a Producer publish More topics or partition and Consumer getting them? Suggest ways how to publish many topics as well as create partition of a topic. I went through many sites but didn't get any proper java code to do such.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka documentation about KafkaConsumer shows pretty well how to subscribe to multiple topics. You simply input a list of strings describing the topics to the `subscribe` function instead of one single string.

[KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

As for the Producer you could use the `send` function multiple times with different topics in each call. A for-loop could be used. You can look at the documentation for the KafkaProducer for inspiration.

[KafkaProducer](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)

Comment: I wanted to know how to do without for-loop as I would be running this program in production where the number of topics would be infinite.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to avoid the for-loop since the ProducerRecord constructor doesn't accept multiple topics. I may be misunderstanding your question though. If you mean that you want to create and publish to new topics on the fly there are configurations in the broker that will let you do this.

Comment: Yes. I want to create and publish to new topics as well as old topics. whichever required by the producer. And later on consumer will get the message as per the topic the choose.